# how to check null value in html textbox?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have a JSP page  where i am fetching value from html textbox.
I want to insert that value into MySQL database.
I want if textbox in empty,null,zero and undefined then insert 0 in database otherwise actual value insert in database.

Here is my code.

```
Strins s1=request.getparameter("edate");
s1="1990-07-16 09:12:45"
int s4=0

<script>
    var a=<%=s1%>
    if(a==null || a==undefined || a=='' || a==0){                
       <% psmnt.setInt(6,s4); %>
    }
    else{
       <% psmnt.setString(6,s1); %>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your texbox `<texarea>` or `<input type="text">`?

If you are using  `<input type="text">`, put default value on it:

```
 <input type="text" value="">
```

While for `<textarea>`, `<textarea></textarea>` should give your default value `""`

So that you only need to check

```
if(a==''){
    ......
}
```

Or if you didn't allow white space too, do this:

```
if(a=='' || a.trim() ==''){
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<script>
if(typeof a == 'undefined' || a == 0) {
// Insert db 0
}
</script>
```

Comment: i used this its  throwing ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Your error comes from JAVA, I gave you js code. You need to check this error's location in order to what is going on